What is the new Date().toISOString() equivalent in SQLite?
I have this JavaScript
let dateTime = new Date().toISOString()
console.log(dateTime)
// 2024-05-01T11:55:51.602Z

And this SQLite
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ', 'now');
-- 2024-05-01T11:53:47.47.812Z

If I try to parse the above
let dateTime = new Date("2024-05-01T11:53:47.47.812Z") 
console.log(dateTime)
// Invalid Date

How do I get the result to retain timezone information and be parsable by new Date()? If I try parsing a toISOString() result it works.
Here are the articles I've read, I'm sure I'm missing something small, but I just can't figure it out

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html (no example for ISO 8601
with timestamp)
https://www.internotes.net/sqlite-dates (has ISO example but no
timestamp)
Select Sqlite date values in ISO 8601 format
(no sqlite answer)


At first glance it seems as though SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M.%fZ', 'now'); works? (I.e. omitting ":%S", which seems to be included in "%f" anyway -- hence the "47.47"? If I understand the docs right, "%f" is "SS.SSS", and "%S" are the seconds. So your "%s.%f" duplicates the seconds)

You're producing the seconds twice, once with %S (as integer) and once with %f (with decimals). You should only use one of both. So drop the %S and the point that you have after it. Both are included already in what %f generates:
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%fZ', 'now');
-- 2024-05-01T11:53:47.812Z

